# sharepoint 2013 sphierarchydatasourcecontrol permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new in developing sharePoint.

I try to use SPHierarchyDataSourceControl of sharepoint to display a SPTreeView of all web, doclibs and folders in my site.

I set the property "Web" to "SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb"
and the "RootWebId" to "SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.ID"

My problem is that all users see full tree - not by their permissions in the site. Any Idea of how to solve it ?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey i tried to reproduce your issue but here everything is shown as it should (as in: links hidden when no access). The control should trim the security automatically

i used this code:

```
<SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl id="doclibDataSource" runat="server" RootContextObject="Web" ShowFolderChildren="true" EnableViewState="false">
</SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl>
<SharePoint:SPTreeView ID="doclibtreeview" runat="server" DataSourceID="doclibDataSource" EnableViewState="false" ExpandDepth="2" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tvselected">
</SharePoint:SPTreeView>
```

Can you post yours?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !!! my Code is the same as what you sent, instead of the "RootContextObject" that I set to null (I got the error "Value does not fall within the expected range." when I set it to "Web"). I'm using this TreeView in User Control that is hosted in MasterPage. Someone suggested to me to use security trimming , but I still didn't find how to use it.

Comment: Security trimming is the general SP term to describe the automatic hiding of elements you don't have access to and should be activated automatically using the SPHierarchyDataSourceControl. I also placed this code in my masterpage just beneath the line: 
<div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
Works like it should here so i can't really help further :(

Comment: Bat, maybe you can try the RootWebId parameter and leave the RootContextObject null

SPSite site = SPControl.GetContextSite(Context);
hdsc.Web = site.RootWeb;
hdsc.RootWebId = site.RootWeb.ID.ToString();
hdsc.RootContextObject = null;

Comment: It didn't solve the problem... :(    But thanks a lot for all your help